# Splitting a timestamp into date and time and insert them into an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I want to get the time and date from a timestamp (miliseconds) and insert them into an associative array. It would look something like this:

```
$array = [ $date -> $time]
```

Right now, I can get the date and time into 2 sepparate arrays, but I want to have it all together, with the time matching the corresponding date. Should I get each timestamp, split it and shove it into an array or is it better to create 2 sepparate arrays and then put them together into a larger one? Any ideas about how I should do this?

Further info: I'm getting the data from a mysql table and I'm already converting the timestamp into seconds so I can manipulate it in php. I'm getting the date and time using

```
 date('G:i', $timestamp)
```

and

```
 date('d-m-y', $timestamp)
```

Comment: Use `array_combine` to combine both arrays to one matching your needed format. http://php.net/array_combine

Comment: What is the column type in the database table? Seems you're converting it to seconds only to convert it back to date/time. Rather redundant.

Comment: `$array = array(date('d-m-y', $timestamp)=>date('G:i', $timestamp))` like this?

Comment: @milankyada yes it would be something like that, but my problem is if I have multiple times in a date. I would want the new values to get pushed  (one key, multiple values) instead of having it overwritten.

Comment: @Marcus I have the dates saved as int numbers. I get the miliseconds in javascript and then shove them as seconds into a table. I did it this way because I have to manipulate the dates both in php and in javascript

Comment: I would `split it and shove it into an array`

Comment: Show how you split that date into 2 arrays, then we will have a better idea about what you are really doing

Comment: Gotcha, misunderstood.

Comment: I suppose you realize that when you do this you can't ever have two times for the same date, right?

Comment: @Mike Yea thats exactly what I'm trying to work around. I tried using in_array to check the keys and then pushing the new value if it already exists.

Comment: In that case I would make it a 2D array. Use the date as the key and add all the times you need.

Comment: @Mike Trying that right now, thanks :)

Comment: Aside my answer: *"If you need more info, feel free to ask. Thanks"* implies your question is not clear enough and therefore *could* fall into the category of "Too broad" or "Low Quality".  Questions should be clear with not only your problem, and your goal but also your attempts to solve it or any understanding you have.

Comment: @ash Just because someone says *""If you need more info, feel free to ask."* doesn't mean the question is unclear. I take it to mean something along the lines of *"I have provided all the details I feel are relevant to the question, however I may have missed something. If this is the case, please let me know what I have missed and I will provide it."*. I agree with the rest of your comment though.

Comment: @Mike fair point. Although in contradiction to my comment I agree with you, It was my long winded way of saying *"you don't need that last sentence, we will ask if need be anyway"*  But I was expressing the implication which quite rightly with this question is not the case.

Comment: @ash OK that makes more sense.

Comment: You're both right. As you can see I'm quite new both at stackoverflow and at php ahah. Thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't add to an array the class DateTime

```
$d1=new DateTime("2012-07-08 11:14:15.638276");
print_r($d1);
```

You can output the format:

```
echo $d1->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'); // 2011-01-01T15:03:01.012345
```

Regards.

Comment: I thought of doing this, but I need to return the dates in each day in another part of the project, so to know which ones to return, I would have the same problem as I'm having now, only further ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the timestamp conforms with a unix timestamp you can do

```
$date = new DateTime();

$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$array = [
           'date' => $date->format('d-m-Y'),
           'time' => $date->format('G:i')
         ];
```

Adjust the formats to suite your needs

Answer (score 0):

> Further info: I'm getting the data from a MySQL table and I'm already converting the timestamp into seconds

Don't do this is not only a bad practice (leap seconds) but it's unnecessary overhead using `DateTime` you can use any valid date format that `strtotime` understands, or provide your own format and value using `createFromFormat`.

A simple example would be:

```
$dateTime = new Datetime($mysqlResult['date_field']);
```

From this in accordance to your requirements you can do something like:

```
$array = [ $dateTime->format('d-m-y') => $dateTime->format('G:i') ];
```

I would also recommend using something like [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which extends PHPs standard DateTime functionality with improvements.

Comment: I don't like having the dates saved like that, my problem is that I have to use ISO8601 format date, which doesn't work in mySQL, so I thought this would be the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Yes it does, it's just a matter of [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321809/format-date-in-mysql-select-as-iso-8601) combined with your MySQL and Server timezone settings. Again, using timestamps in milliseconds or seconds violates leap seconds and will cause date mismatches later on in time.

Comment: I'll try to fix it after I'm done with this then. Thanks.