# Convert YYYY-mm-dd from mySql into Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have a date from mysql like :

```
var a = '2016-09-09';
var date = new Date(a);
```

And it returns :

Sat Jul 09 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

It is supposed to be : Sat Sept 09 2016.
Why it shows July for the month ? Any ideas ?

This is the complete code :

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, order, tgl)
        {
            var date2 = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>';

            var a = new Date(tgl);
            var b = new Date(date2);
            console.log('Order : ' + order);
            console.log('today : ' + a);
            console.log('tgl : ' + b)

            if (b <= a)
            {
                var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                icon:image2,
                map: map,
                title: '' + order
                });             
            }
            else
            {
                var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                icon:image1,
                map: map,
                title: '' + order
                });             
              }
        }
```

I just want to compare two dates and show the different marker if todays date less than date from mysql.

Comment: I get `sept 8th` https://jsfiddle.net/vcjf5t5r/, also the 9th is Friday in Sept. You sure you have the right PHP date being returned? Assuming `tgl` is `'2016-09-09'`.. Also there is no `mysql` in the question, tag removed.

Comment: I've already test it with console.log(tgl); it returns 2016-09-09. But when i change into var a = new Date(tgl); And log it, it return into Jul for the month

Comment: What is `tgl` logged as?

Comment: `addMarker` can only work correctly when it is generated by PHP, otherwise `var date2 = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>';` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `Date.parse` function accepts a [RFC2822 or ISO 8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) formatted date. If you a different format is used it may return an unexpected value (eg. does not understand the date format used).

For a PHP-provided date you can use the `<?php echo date('c'); ?>` or `<?php echo date(DateTime::ISO8601); ?>`. Either will return an ISO8601-formatted date which JavaScript can parse.

If using MySQL you can either convert by importing the date as a PHP timestamp using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object then format the output as ISO8601 similar to what I posted above or just have MySQL return the value formatted as ISO8601: [Format date in MySQL SELECT as ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321809/format-date-in-mysql-select-as-iso-8601)