# Parsing datetime from ISO 8601 using Spark SQL

Tags: date, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321809/format-date-in-mysql-select-as-iso-8601) but the other way around.

My `date`s are in this format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`, I want two columns `YYYY-MM-DD` and `hh:mm` that I can concat, if I want to, for certain queries.

I get an error when using `convert()`; I assume this is not supported currently with Spark SQL.

When I use `date(datetime)` or `timestamp(datetime)`, I get all null values returned. However, `minute(datetime)` and `hour(datetime)` work.

Currently, using this

```
concat(date,' ', hour,':', (case when minute < 10 then concat('0',minute) else minute end)) as DateTime
from (select OtherDateOnlyColumn as date, minute(datetime) as minute, hour(datetime) as hour from ...)
```

which is obviously not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with date()  on this query and it works:

```
select date(datetime) from df
```

Maybe the date in your table is string type; you should check the data types of the columns with

```
DESCRIBE your_table
```

If the date is string type, you can use `cast(datetime as timestamp) as newTimestamp` which is available in [Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#cast(java.lang.String)) to convert the datetime back to a timestamp type and use variants of `date_format(newTimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm')` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. use date function in Spark SQL.

Example ISO 8601 date format:

2017-05-12T00:00:00.000Z

```
select date(datetime) as parsed_date from table
```