# How to convert to a timestamp which is like 2019-03-25T00:27:46.985-0500 to 2019-03-25 00:27:46 in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to convert the timestamp which looks like 2019-03-25T00:27:46.985-0500 to this format2019-03-25 00:27:46

Using Spark v2.3.0
Scala v2.11.8

time    ColA    ColB    ColC 2019-03-25T00:27:46.985-0500   A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.960-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.839-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.596-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.559-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.535-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.453-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.405-0500  A   B   C 2019-03-25T00:27:46.393-0500  A   B   C

```
val log = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("multiLine", "true")
      .load("time.csv")

scala> log.printSchema
root
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ColA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ColB: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ColC: string (nullable = true)

val logs = log.withColumn("Id", monotonicallyIncreasingId()+1)
val df = spark.sql("select Id, time, ColA from logs")
```

Input: 2019-03-25T00:27:46.985-05:00
Expected Output: 2019-03-25 00:27:46

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing datetime from ISO 8601 using Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108586/parsing-datetime-from-iso-8601-using-spark-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .selectExpr with date_format function

```
val log2 = log.selectExpr(
    "date_format(time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
    )
```