# Mysql DATE field selected in format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-HH:mm

Tags: php, mysql, simpledateformat, jqwidget

I'm using JqxCharts from JqWidgets.

Using a PHP file to get Json data for the Graph.

In Mysql query I do something like this:

```
SELECT fecha, Qty
FROM somedatabase

2016-05-01     5
2016-07-21     55
2016-08-16     33
```

The "fecha" field is simple DATE format.
But when it display  in the graph I always get a wrong date (1 day less)

[Apparently it has to do something with Date Format conversion from javascript.](http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/date-datafield-timezone-handling/)

And I need to get the date from MySql in format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-HH:mm"

How can I get this format from my actual Query?

**UPDATE: SOLVED.**

Thanks to "tadman", to help me to understand. I searched how to select Mysql ISO 8601, [so I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321809/format-date-in-mysql-select-as-iso-8601)

So now I just updated the Query to:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%dT%T-06:00'), Qty
FROM somedatabase
```

By the way if someone is looking for this, the "T-06:00" is the UTC for Mexico.

Comment: That's just [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). MySQL's internal format is a form of that as well, but the `T` is omitted. If you need to do date reformatting for whatever reason, do it in PHP, not your query.

Comment: that's not what I was looking for, but that helped me to understand it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "tadman", to help me to understand. I searched how to select Mysql ISO 8601, [so I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321809/format-date-in-mysql-select-as-iso-8601)

So now I just updated the Query to:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%dT%T-06:00'), Qty
FROM somedatabase
```

> By the way if someone is looking for this, the "T-06:00" is the UTC
>   for Mexico.

Comment: As a warning, that's correct today but on October 30th it flips to -06:00 from -05:00. You may want to check what the time-zone offset is for any given date, something complicated by the fact that the time-zone switches after midnight.

Comment: that's true, I was wondering what hapens in that case, cause it actually its always a -6 Zone, but since it has Daylight Saving Time, it changes, not sure if changes as you say, if it is the case then I'ĺl need another aproach to this problem with dates in Mysql and javascript

Comment: In general terms dates don't have time zones, but times *might*. Like anything with dates, test this exhaustively to be sure you've got it right and pay particular attention to the odd cases around DST flips and leap years.

Comment: They don't have, and actually the field is supposed to be only date (yyyy-mm-dd), not time, or zone, but this odd thing happens when getting the data in Json for JqxCharts, I'll check this behavior, plus the hour change oct-30 is near, thank you