# How to query the unmodified timestamp inside a JSON object using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, timestamp, iso8601

I would like to query a JSON object containing a MySQL TIMESTAMP named 'time':

```
SELECT time, JSON_OBJECT('t', time, 'v', value) AS value FROM values
```

But unfortunately, MySQL transforms the ISO 8601 formatted timestamp `"2019-04-04T12:00:00.000Z"` automatically into this presentation `"2019-04-04 12:00:00.000000"`. See the following response:

```
{
  "time": "2019-04-04T12:00:00.000Z",
  "value": {
    "t": "2019-04-04 12:00:00.000000",
    "v": 30
  }
}
```

Is it possible to access time keeping its original type and presentation (as `"2019-04-04T12:00:00.000Z"`) inside a JSON object? What is the recommended and clean approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to make an ISO 8601 format date in an expression.

See [Format date in MySQL SELECT as ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321809/format-date-in-mysql-select-as-iso-8601)

In your case:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), 
  JSON_OBJECT('t', DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), 'v', value) AS value 
FROM values
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT v.time_8601, JSON_OBJECT('t', v.time_8601, 'v', v.value) AS value
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') AS time_8601, value FROM values) AS v
```

---

Re your comment:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html says:

> *MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.*

The non-hacky way is to use that format. If you want to use a different format (even an ISO format), you must use the DATE_FORMAT() and STR_TO_DATE() functions.

There's a function [GET_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format) that returns the format string for some popular choices. But it doesn't support ISO 8601 format (that's noted specifically in the manual, as though this question has come up before).

```
-- formats in ISO 9075 like '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', NOT ISO 8601
DATE_FORMAT(time, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME, 'ISO'))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I wonder if this is the 'recommended' way, because it seems a bit hacky – like a workaround – to me. Do you know why MySQL modifies the time (with type `TIMESTAMP`) and outputs it in different ways – depending on the uage of `JSON_OBJECT`?